# load QPixmap doesn't work on vista

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, qt, setup-project, setup-deployment

I really need your help, I created an application that has an image browser in it. I'm using qt version 4.7.1 along with visual studio 2010 c++. The application works perfectly on my computer; but when I try it on another computer (windows vista) - using VS deployment - it isn't loaded. After googling a lot it seems that I some plugin should be included in the setup project.

Please help me out guys.

Comment: As you already mention you have to ship the plugin DLL's with your application.

Comment: I added the qjpegd4.dll to the setup project to plugins/qjpegd4 but I didn't add any code for that just in the setup project; so I'm not sure if I'm doing this correctly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to copy `%QTDIR%\plugins\imageformats\qjpeg4.dll` to `%YOURAPPLICATIONDIR%\imageformats\qjpeg4.dll`.

Comment: I did that for qjpegd4 because I'm building in debug mode but it doesn't work .. should I include qjpeg4.dll also?

Comment: Poka Yoke: `%APPLICATIONDIR%` has to be the directory of you executable. (Maybe you have to copy the folder imageformats to your "Debug" directory.)

Comment: Thanks .. you got it right, my problem was that I add it to %YOURAPPLICATIONDIR%\plugins\imageformats\ and it doesn't work but when I removed the plugins it worked. thank you again :)